# Python3.x Changing ' ' into an integer/ float. Calculating average from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, python-3.5

I am trying to change the '' in a list to an integer or float. Lets say I have a list

```
    allprices = ['', '', '', 1.2, 3.2, 1.8, '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

I want to change the empty strings into floats or ints I am not sure about that part but pretty sure they have to be floats at the end as I am going to calculate averages. Now for that I have another list called

```
    averages = []
```

the list "allprices" is a list of lists of elements so formed by sub lists basically. It has 6 levels. I tried to replace '' with 0 and it worked. But couldn't figure out a way how to make that change with a command. There are some examples and commands I found here or in other forums but didn't work for me. The first thing I tried was

```
    var = ''
    var1= 0
    var = var1
```

but this gives some error. I also tried making it a float directly but didn't work either. Please help or direct me to another title so I can figure it out. BTW i am new to programming so what I try to do might not look like a convenient way to tackle this problem but I am happy as long as it works for me.

Comment: What does "command" mean in this context?

Comment: Your example list has many empty strings.  How do you know which replacement value to use for each one?

Comment: If you're only storing prices how do you end up with strings and floats together? Just curious, maybe it could be solved at the moment `allprices` is generated

Comment: The values are read into the list from a csv file. Those prices are fruit prices for each month from different years. If a fruit wasn't on sale in a month it has no value. that's how it is formed with strings and floats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just ignore them in the sum when you calculate the average:

```
>>> allprices = ['', '', '', 1.2, 3.2, 1.8, '', '', '', '', '', '']
>>> sum(x for x in allprices if x)/len(allprices)
0.5166666666666667
```

Note - this relies on the 'non truthiness' of `''`. If you have list elements that otherwise are 'truthy' (such as `' '`)but should be filtered, adjust your if clause appropriately:

```
>>> allprices = ['', '', '', 1.2, 3.2, 1.8, '', '', '', '', '', ' ']
>>> sum(x for x in allprices if isinstance(x, (float, int)))/len(allprices)
0.5166666666666667
```

If you might have classes of numbers that are not `int` or `float` use the abstract base class [Numbers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html) to filter:

```
>>> import numbers
>>> sum(x for x in allprices if isinstance(x, numbers.Number))/len(allprices)
0.5166666666666667
```

---

If you want to actually replace `''` with `0` use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [e if e else 0 for e in allprices]
[0, 0, 0, 1.2, 3.2, 1.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

or,

```
>>> [e if isinstance(e, (float, int)) else 0 for e in allprices]
[0, 0, 0, 1.2, 3.2, 1.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I Believe I didn't make myself very clear I am not trying to calculate the average of "allprices". All prices is a actually a list formed buy sub lists. it has 5 other lists as elements of allprices and those 5 lists have 12 items each in them. I will try post my code so you can see what I am exactly working on.

Comment: You title says `Calculating average from a list` Please clarify what you are trying to do...

Comment: "allprices" is actually a list like this

    allprices =[  ['',  '',  '',  '', 1.0, 2.0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.1,  '', '',  ''],
           ['',  '',  '', 1.2, 1.0, 2.0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.1,  '',  '',  ''],
           ['',  '',  '', 1.2,  '', 1.8, 1.3, 1.1,  '',  '', '',  ''],
           ['',  '',  '',  '', 1.0, 2.0, 1.2, 1.2,  '',  '',  '',  ''],
           ['',  '',  '',  '', 1.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.8, 1.9, 2.2]    ]

Comment: Each sublist has 12 items. I calculate the average for allprices[1][3]. In each list I take the 4th value add them together and divide 5. I believe this is more clear now. I already got that covered I am just trying to get rid of the '' sign so I can make the average calculation while appending the result into a new list.

Answer (score 2):

And another solution with `filter`:

```
>>> sum(filter(None, allprices))/len(allprices)
0.5166666666666667
```

`filter(None, ...)` will weed out all elements which are falsy, for example the empty string or the value 0. The latter is fine because it won't make an impact when calculating the sum.